# Codeigniter 3.0 Session create after session destroy

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I have upgraded my codeigniter 2.x to 3.0 and I am facing session issue. My site has multi language support so I want to keep language session even when user logout from account. I have implemented logout functionality as mentioned below.

```
   $lang = $this->session->userdata('language');        
   $this->session->sess_destroy();          
   $this->session->sess_create(); 
   $this->session->set_userdata(array('language' => $lang));
```

As CI 3.x   sess_create() has been removed  so I'm unable to create language session after destroying session. I know we can use cookies helper instead of session but I need to make many changes if I have to use cookies instead of session.

Comment: what is the purpose of keeping session after logout. No point i think

Comment: Probably should make it clear, What is the question?

Comment: Abdulla my site supports english and danish language support. Even user logout from account he should be able browse site general pages in user selected language.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Note that here `sesssion_var` is a variable name in which you are storing your session

```
$session = $this->session->userdata('sesssion_var');
$language_session = $session['language'];
$this->session->set_userdata('sesssion_var',$language_session);
```

Comment: Thanks Vidhi. I don't see any difference of my code shown in the question.

Comment: I have not removed / delete session. I have just updated session array. @Arvind kumar anugula

Answer (score 0):

Use `unset_userdata('sessionnamewhichhastobedestroy')` rather  than `sess_destroy()`.

Or if you use `sess_destroy()` then set `default` value in `$lang`